# Is there an entity in Moqui that is similar to that of System Properties in OFBiz?

Tags: moqui

I am not able to figure out that how should I store system related information in Moqui.

For example, if I am using the HiveMind application for a particular organization (ABC Corp), I have to hard code the value while making records for the particular organization. I could not find any suitable entity that will allow me to handle this particular case.

So is there any method by which I can handle this particular case?

For example, when I am creating users and clients in the HiveMind application, there is no record in the database that will specify that the Users are employees of a particular organization.

For clients they are just stored in the Organization entity and no relationship exists that will specify that. I can handle that case by creating a party relationship whenever a new user or client is created.

But I will have to hard code the value of the Party with which I want to create the relationship. Suppose ABC corp is using the HiveMind application, I would have to hard code ABC corp's party Id whenever I create a new user or client. Rather that hard coding this value, it would be more efficient for me to fetch this particular value from the database. Whenever a new Organization wants to use the application, I will just change it in the database and the service code will remain as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "system related information" and "the value"? Could you share an example?

Comment: Updated the description for the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an application design question and not an aspect of the framework, but I'll share some thoughts on it.

Business level configuration should generally be done in the database in structures (entities) that are designed for the purpose. Sometimes it general values are needed, but this should be the exception and only rare cases. In Moqui the way to handle user or user group preferences is to use the UserPreference and UserGroupPreference, and for all users use the ALL_USERS group that is standard in Moqui (all users are automatically part of this group). This can be done directly on the entities or using the relevant methods on the UserFacade (ec.user).

That said, from a business and application design perspective for apps based on Mantle (for others reading in, this is the business artifacts project based on Moqui) I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. If you want to support multiple organizations when creating an employee you should have a field on the form to select which organization the employee is part of (and then create the PartyRelationship record as you implied).

In HiveMind there can be multiple vendor organizations with people in different roles associated with them. When creating a project you select the vendor and client organizations for the particular project so we know who to bill from and to, which users are involved with different aspects of the project, etc.

If you do want to support just one vendor organization you may as well hard-code it and not make it visible or selectable anywhere in the application, and make it part of the "seed" data of the app in the more strict sense of the term seed data as data that code depends on directly (i.e. uses "hard-coded", though that term has negative implications that are often unjustified, directly use string values are often quite useful and improve clarity and maintainability).